# How to add a text input, where a user can filter the list of students by their name (both first and last name)

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I'm trying to create a text search where I can filter through the names from an api.

It should look something like this:

https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/part3.mp4

I'm able to fetch everything from the api successfully I'm just having a hard time creating a filter to search through the first names and last names.

My API looks like this:
https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students

```js
fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(function(data) {
    let students = data.students;

    return students.map(function(student) {
      let values = student.grades;
      let firstNames = student.firstName;

      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(values[i], 10); //don't forget to add the base
      }

      var avg = sum / values.length;

      let li = createNode('li'),
        img = createNode('img'),
        span = createNode('span');

      img.src = student.pic;


      span.innerHTML = `<b><li>${firstNames} ${student.lastName}</li></b>
                          <li>${student.company} </li> 
                          <li>${student.email} </li> 
                          <li>Average: ${avg}</li>`;


    })
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  })
```

Comment: If you click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55596169/edit) then `[<>]` stack snippet editor, then you can create a [mcve] with an example JSON string to parse. Then it is much easier for us to add relevant code

Answer (score 1):

First we fix your code so it runs and produces valid HTML (spans do not have LIs)

Use the first LI content to filter using a dynamic regular expression.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(`{ "students": [ { "city": "Fushë-Muhurr", "company": "Yadel", "email": "iorton0@imdb.com", "firstName": "Ingaberg", "grades": [ "78", "100", "92", "86", "89", "88", "91", "87" ], "id": "1", "lastName": "Orton", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/voluptasdictablanditiis.jpg", "skill": "Oracle" }, { "city": "Sanghan", "company": "Avamm", "email": "cboards1@weibo.com", "firstName": "Clarke", "grades": [ "75", "89", "95", "93", "99", "82", "89", "76" ], "id": "2", "lastName": "Boards", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/voluptasautreprehenderit.jpg", "skill": "Sports" }, { "city": "Kugesi", "company": "Skalith", "email": "lromanet2@wired.com", "firstName": "Laurens", "grades": [ "88", "90", "79", "82", "81", "99", "94", "73" ], "id": "3", "lastName": "Romanet", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/aspernaturnonsapiente.jpg", "skill": "Employee Handbooks" }, { "city": "Krajan", "company": "Mybuzz", "email": "bskitt3@aboutads.info", "firstName": "Berti", "grades": [ "88", "93", "92", "81", "95", "98", "77", "94" ], "id": "4", "lastName": "Skitt", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/autautdeserunt.jpg", "skill": "Nutrition Education" }, { "city": "Huiqi", "company": "Avavee", "email": "msummerley4@craigslist.org", "firstName": "Mureil", "grades": [ "71", "81", "72", "92", "79", "82", "91", "90" ], "id": "5", "lastName": "Summerley", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/consequaturdelectusquis.jpg", "skill": "ISO 14971" }, { "city": "Jianghong", "company": "Twinte", "email": "rcoryndon5@cargocollective.com", "firstName": "Robbyn", "grades": [ "97", "92", "72", "99", "92", "92", "79", "96" ], "id": "6", "lastName": "Coryndon", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/autautdeserunt.jpg", "skill": "Cinema 4D" }, { "city": "Sanxi", "company": "Buzzster", "email": "seykel6@examiner.com", "firstName": "Sheena", "grades": [ "74", "95", "75", "95", "85", "97", "88", "85" ], "id": "7", "lastName": "Eykel", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/utquamut.jpg", "skill": "Ulead VideoStudio" }, { "city": "Huancheng", "company": "Edgeblab", "email": "mewen7@ycombinator.com", "firstName": "Minnnie", "grades": [ "80", "100", "97", "78", "99", "99", "76", "85" ], "id": "8", "lastName": "Ewen", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/nesciuntrerumlibero.jpg", "skill": "Vulcan" }, { "city": "Luoxiong", "company": "Fadeo", "email": "riban8@hubpages.com", "firstName": "Rory", "grades": [ "70", "100", "75", "96", "83", "90", "94", "92" ], "id": "9", "lastName": "Iban", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/autemporroplaceat.jpg", "skill": "EE4" }, { "city": "Toulon", "company": "Yakidoo", "email": "lroxby9@cam.ac.uk", "firstName": "Lenna", "grades": [ "70", "99", "81", "83", "78", "95", "81", "76" ], "id": "10", "lastName": "Roxby", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/doloribusquitempora.jpg", "skill": "LPS" }, { "city": "Lazo", "company": "Photolist", "email": "rfitzalana@parallels.com", "firstName": "Rosalynd", "grades": [ "98", "93", "78", "87", "99", "89", "97", "81" ], "id": "11", "lastName": "FitzAlan", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/utquamut.jpg", "skill": "Geography" }, { "city": "Bichura", "company": "Babblestorm", "email": "srapellib@adobe.com", "firstName": "Stephanie", "grades": [ "83", "97", "70", "96", "75", "98", "90", "71" ], "id": "12", "lastName": "Rapelli", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/enimpariaturoptio.jpg", "skill": "Identity Management" }, { "city": "Chvalšiny", "company": "Mynte", "email": "mmacdirmidc@plala.or.jp", "firstName": "Maire", "grades": [ "87", "73", "85", "98", "73", "95", "75", "97" ], "id": "13", "lastName": "MacDirmid", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/aspernaturnonsapiente.jpg", "skill": "Outdoor Advertising" }, { "city": "Itaparica", "company": "Photospace", "email": "nshepherdd@desdev.cn", "firstName": "Nicoline", "grades": [ "90", "73", "88", "95", "71", "100", "80", "86" ], "id": "14", "lastName": "Shepherd", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/nonipsaet.jpg", "skill": "Amazon VPC" }, { "city": "Praia da Vitória", "company": "Vitz", "email": "ythornse@github.com", "firstName": "Yoshi", "grades": [ "78", "78", "96", "92", "80", "82", "91", "99" ], "id": "15", "lastName": "Thorns", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/voluptasdictablanditiis.jpg", "skill": "DMR" }, { "city": "Sambir", "company": "Twitterwire", "email": "mtothef@shutterfly.com", "firstName": "Marna", "grades": [ "88", "74", "76", "89", "75", "97", "75", "86" ], "id": "16", "lastName": "Tothe", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/utquamut.jpg", "skill": "PFI" }, { "city": "Sarulla", "company": "Blogpad", "email": "okearyg@g.co", "firstName": "Orelia", "grades": [ "78", "92", "86", "80", "82", "95", "76", "84" ], "id": "17", "lastName": "Keary", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/enimpariaturoptio.jpg", "skill": "General Surgery" }, { "city": "Ochakovo-Matveyevskoye", "company": "Mydeo", "email": "mswaith@cafepress.com", "firstName": "Moses", "grades": [ "84", "82", "92", "74", "87", "98", "86", "73" ], "id": "18", "lastName": "Swait", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/velitnonquibusdam.jpg", "skill": "Sales Tax" }, { "city": "Youxi Chengguanzhen", "company": "Avaveo", "email": "fnusseyi@skyrock.com", "firstName": "Fonsie", "grades": [ "100", "75", "84", "91", "100", "97", "98", "87" ], "id": "19", "lastName": "Nussey", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/remtemporavelit.jpg", "skill": "Urbanism" }, { "city": "Limoges", "company": "Tazzy", "email": "srydingsj@phoca.cz", "firstName": "Skelly", "grades": [ "89", "81", "77", "93", "96", "96", "70", "79" ], "id": "20", "lastName": "Rydings", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/etporroalias.jpg", "skill": "IFTA" }, { "city": "Łobżenica", "company": "Quatz", "email": "obrennekek@yellowbook.com", "firstName": "Olly", "grades": [ "81", "74", "77", "82", "74", "88", "86", "87" ], "id": "21", "lastName": "Brenneke", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/velitnonquibusdam.jpg", "skill": "ATM Networks" }, { "city": "Divo", "company": "Gigazoom", "email": "nbadwickl@nifty.com", "firstName": "Norby", "grades": [ "73", "99", "91", "92", "85", "96", "95", "73" ], "id": "22", "lastName": "Badwick", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/delenitiestdolorum.jpg", "skill": "Media Relations" }, { "city": "Sortavala", "company": "Eamia", "email": "mmichiem@nifty.com", "firstName": "Melody", "grades": [ "100", "83", "76", "71", "93", "95", "73", "88" ], "id": "23", "lastName": "Michie", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/sitlaborecorrupti.jpg", "skill": "PC Games" }, { "city": "Taupo", "company": "Midel", "email": "jwillougheyn@psu.edu", "firstName": "Janice", "grades": [ "71", "80", "83", "99", "91", "95", "81", "75" ], "id": "24", "lastName": "Willoughey", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/dolordoloremassumenda.jpg", "skill": "Kondor+" }, { "city": "Krajandadapmulyo", "company": "Wikibox", "email": "ggallymoreo@mashable.com", "firstName": "Geraldine", "grades": [ "97", "71", "89", "85", "85", "87", "92", "75" ], "id": "25", "lastName": "Gallymore", "pic": "https://storage.googleapis.com/hatchways-app.appspot.com/assessments/data/frontend/images/sitlaborecorrupti.jpg", "skill": "WTL" } ] }`);

let students = data.students;

students.forEach(function(student) {
  let values = student.grades;
  let firstNames = student.firstName;
  let sum = values.reduce((a,b) => +a + +b, 0); //convert to ints before summing
  let avg = (sum / values.length).toFixed(2);

  let card = document.createElement("div"), // wrapper
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    img = document.createElement('img'),
    ul = document.createElement('ul');

  ul.classList.add("filter");

  img.src = student.pic;

  ul.innerHTML = `<li><b>${firstNames} ${student.lastName}</b></li>
                          <li>${student.company} </li> 
                          <li>${student.email} </li> 
                          <li>Average: ${avg}</li>`;

  card.appendChild(img);
  card.appendChild(ul);
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(card)
})
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  re = new RegExp(val.split(" ").join("|"), "gi"); // creates /joe|blow/gi
  document.querySelectorAll("ul.filter").forEach(ele => {
    const words = ele.firstChild.textContent.split(' ');
    let found = words.some(c => re.test(c));
    ele.closest("div").style.display = found ? "" : "none"; // toggle the card
  });
})

//Alternatives for the textContent:
// ul.setAttribute("data-filter", `${firstNames} ${student.lastName}`);
// `${firstNames} ${student.lastName}`.split(" ").forEach(name => ul.classList.add(name) )
```

```css
ul {list-style: none}
#container img { float:left; padding:5px } 
#filter { position:fixed; margin-left:300px }
```

```html
<input id="filter" />
<div id="container"></div>
```